# Finding the DOI for a paper

Tags: reference-request, journals

How can we find the DOI of an old paper. For example, what are the DOI of the following papers?

1. Anderson, D.D. and Jayaram, C., 1995. Regular lattices. *Studia Scientiarum Mathematicarum Hungarica*, 30(3), pp.379-388.
2. ‎Iorgulescu, A., 2004. Classes of BCK algebras-Part III. *Preprint series of the Institute of Mathematics of the Romanian Academy*, 3, pp.1-37.
3. Thakare, N.K., Manjarekar, C.S. and Maeda, S., 1988. Abstract spectral theory II: minimal characters and minimal spectrums of multiplicative lattices. *Acta Sci. Math*, 52, pp.53-67.

Comment: I have no idea about these particular journals, but not all papers have DOIs.  For instance, not all journal are available online.

Comment: One great method (with at least 90% success, in my experience) is mathscinet, or their free lookup tool [MR lookup](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mrlookup). If you set it to BibTeX format, very often the DOI is included (if there is one!).

Comment: I looked up your three papers on MathSciNet. They are MR1353613, MR2648142 (although this is a slightly different version, it seems), and MR0957788. None of them list DOIs.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460309/finding-the-doi-for-a-paper#comment1193748_460309), do you know any effective method for searching MRef directly?  I tend to find it almost useless on queries unless they are literally cut and pasted from MathSciNet entries; almost everything else it seems to regard as too ambiguous to answer.  But that was a while ago, and maybe it has improved since then.

Comment: DOI's started to be assigned in 1997; large publishers retro-actively assign DOI's, small publishers do not (it is not free); preprints (like your second reference) are unlikely to have a DOI, unless they are on arXiv

Comment: Related: [Does every mathematics article have a DOI (Digital Object Identifier)?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/178421).

Comment: You want the DOI for downloading them? The whole volume which contains the first paper can be downloaded in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/35157967.pdf. For the other two, Google Scholar does not give any link.

Comment: [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/) offers much the same service as MathSciNet, in particular indexes maths papers including doi's where available. In addition, it's free to use.